# Tomcat issues inside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am very new to Tomcat and web development in general and apologize for what may be a very silly question.

Consider 2 situations:

**1.**

I start Tomcat outside of Eclipse.
I use eclipse to create a war file.
I deploy it via admin console.
All is ok

**2.**

I start Tomcat via Eclipse
I can't access admin console

http://localhost:8080/manager/html greets me with 404 error
Same page is behaving properly when Tomcat is started outside of Eclipse

Please advise

Why might the issue be?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why might the issue be?

You need to configure Eclipse to **take control of your Tomcat installation**. To do so:

- double click on the **Tomcat Server** in the **Servers** view
- under **Server Locations**, select **Use Tomcat installation**

This is illustrated on the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: This saved me from a what I expected to be a lengthy investigation. Is there anything that can cause this option ("Use Tomcat installation") to change of it's own accord. I had everything working yesterday, and then after a new deployment of my web application...nothing would work. I followed your advice in this answer and now it works again. Anyway, it's fixed now.

Comment: I exactly have the same issue, but "server locations" menu is grayed out in my Eclipse (Kepler on OS X). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse creates a new Tomcat configuration separate to your Tomcat installation, in the 'Servers' project. This allows Eclipse to deploy webapps without interfering with anything you've done in your installation (via the manager app or by editing config files manually).

You **can** reconfigure Eclipse so that it uses the config from your Tomcat installation (see Pascal's answer), or to re-enable the manager app - but read the [WTP Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ) first as there are good reasons for it working the way it does. I don't recall ever needing to do this - the 'Servers' tab in Eclipse lets you deploy/start/stop/debug/configure apps as required.

Comment: OK, but when i start/ stop Tomcat via eclipse or outside of eclipse- we are dealing with the same instance of the web server, right? In that respect shouldn't same URL work? Just curious

Comment: Not really. Tomcat is just a 'container' for Java web applications - the URLs it responds to depend on which apps you've configured it to run. An 'instance' is really a combination of the Tomcat code (there's one copy of this - wherever you installed Tomcat) and the configuration (server.xml, webapps/ directory, etc.) which there can be multiple copies of. The manager is just another web application whose purpose is to add/remove stuff from the webapps/ directory, and since Eclipse does this job for you, Eclipse disables the manager when it creates a Tomcat instance in the 'Servers' project.